# Escape "useFactory" when overriting a provider in Angular2

Tags: http, angular, factory, provider

My problem is related to the *overrite* of @angular/http's Http module. I'm intercepting every single Http request by using the next code:

```
export let fakeBackendProvider = {
  // intercepts every single Http call
  provide: Http,
  useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, options: BaseRequestOptions) => {
    backend.connections.subscribe((connection) => {
       // here I treat requests for their urls
       if(connection.endsWith('/example/') {
           // ...
       }

       // here I'd like to CONTINUE the normal execution as it is,
       // as if THIS call had never entered in "useFactory" peace of code
       if(connection.endsWith('/example.noprovider/') {
           // GO ON
       }
    })
    return new Http(backend, options)
  },
  deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
}
```

**What I need**

- GET data from JSON file via HTTP request

**The problem**

My interceptor (the code above) always stands before HTTP calls, but depending on the URL of the HTTP request, I need to use that interceptor or not.

**What am I looking for**

Some functionality to "separate" routines like:

*INSIDE THE INTERCEPTOR*

```
if(url === 'useinterceptor) {
  // USE INTERCEPTOR
}
if(url === 'notuseinterceptor') {
  // USE HTTP GET OPERATION AS IT IS 
}
```

Comment: would be good to know what exactly the problem is ? :-)

Comment: Yep, sorry for that. The thing is that I'm sending an http request to get a json file on my code. And could not find how to implement that operation while passing through the useFactory block of code.

I'd like to continue the operation as it is, kinda "next" for Observables.

thnx

@user1713747

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give a [mcve] that explains the issue.

Comment: I used this Http Interceptor example. Maybe it helps. 
https://www.illucit.com/blog/2016/03/angular2-http-authentication-interceptor/